# i need to understand a solution to a row sum odd numbers method in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math

The question:

Calculate the row sums of this triangle from the row index.

```
row_sum_odd_numbers(1); # 1
row_sum_odd_numbers(2); # 3 + 5 = 8
row_sum_odd_numbers(3); # 7 + 9 + 11 = 27
```

...

```
Test.assert_equals(row_sum_odd_numbers(1), 1)

Test.assert_equals(row_sum_odd_numbers(2), 8)

Test.assert_equals(row_sum_odd_numbers(13), 2197)

Test.assert_equals(row_sum_odd_numbers(19), 6859)

Test.assert_equals(row_sum_odd_numbers(41), 68921)
```

The solution to the question is as follows:

```
def row_sum_odd_numbers(n)
  return n**3
end
```

I understand that this code returns the answer. I don't understand how it returns the answer. Why does the 3rd exponent of n return the row sum of odd numbers?

Comment: It is just a mathematical trick. It cannot be explained, but you can get the pattern!

Comment: It would probably help to show the triangle and/or problem definition. It is the qualities of the triangle that make it resolve to this simple answer. Maybe the question could be adapted for maths.stackexchange if getiing n**3 from the design of the triangle seems obscure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just math calculation:)

lets find out what is the first summand:
before first summand we have `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-1` odd numbers, their amount is `((n-1)*n)/2`. So, first summand after them is 
 `((n-1)*n)/2  * 2 + 1 = (n-1)*n + 1`.

Now we should just calculate our sum:

`row_sum_odd_numbers(n)= (n-1)*n + 1 + (n-1)*n + 3 + (n-1)*n + 5  +...+ (n-1)*n + 2*n - 1 =` 
`(n-1)*n*n + 1 + 3 + 5 + ... + 2*n -1 = n^3 - n^2 + n^2 = n^3`

Comment: Please format this for readability. It'll help the OP and those who are searching for a similar solution.

Answer (score 3):

Through row `n` there are `1+2+..+n` odd numbers. As `1,2,3,...` is an algebraic progression, the sum of the first `n` terms equals:

```
n(n+1)/2
```

Since the ith odd number equals `1+2(i-1)`, the last odd number in row `n` equals:

```
p = 1+2(n(n+1)/2-1) = n^2+n-1
```

meaning that the sum of the odd `n` odd numbers in row `n` equals:

```
p+(p-2)+...+p-2(n-1) = np-2(0+1+...+n-1)
                     = np-2n(n-1)/2
                     = np-n^2+n
```

(`0+1+...+n-1` equals the sum of the first `n` terms of the algebraic progression `0,1,2,3...`). Substituting for `p`, this equals

```
n(n^2+n-1)-n^2+n = n^3
```

proving the assertion.

Answer (score 1):

First, one needs to calculate the number the `k`th row starts with. If you draw the triangle, it's not hard to realize that this is

```
1 + \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}2*j =
                        = 1 + (2 + ... + 2*(k-1))
                        = 1 + (2 + 2(k-1))/2*(k-1)
                        = k^2 - k + 1
```

The sum of the numbers in the corresponding row of the triangle is then equal to the sum of `k` numbers starting with `k^2 - k + 1` with increment of `2`. Thus the result is

```
k*( k^2 - k + 1 + k^2 - k + 1 + (k-1)*2 )/2 = k*k^2 = k^3
```